# What type of applications/projects can I create using Assembly Language?

Tags: assembly

I am in my third semester of my university. I hardly know anything about writing assembly languages: I just used MASM and wrote `mov` and `add eax,var1` sorts of instructions.

Can we create programs in Assembly Language similar to what we can do in C/C++?

Can you please recommend any sample projects that have been built using Assembly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write any kind of application in assembler.  The primary difference between it and other languages such as C (and what is likely confusing you) is that Assembler is extremely low level.  It takes many, many instructions in assembly to do what can easily be done in a single line of code in C.  This is, in essence, why languages such as C were created; to make writing programs quicker and easier since they can do in 1 line what it takes many, many assembly instructions to do.  You also have to understand a lot about how the computer "thinks" to write an assembly program.

The big up-side to assembly is that it is just flat out fast.  C and other languages have to make assumptions about what you are trying to do to save you time.  In assembly, you can avoid all of the extra overhead that comes from those assumptions, which makes your program very, very fast.

It is well worth learning some assembler in college as it gives you a very big insight into how the computer is "thinking" and what benefits C and other languages are really providing for you.

Comment: The big problem is that without a compiler, **you** will have to figure out all the assumptions yourself, including how this years CPU model handles each machine instruction and how reordering the code affects parallel execution units, the branch prediction and cache efficiency. You really have to be like a computer to be able to optimize the code properly - or like a compiler!

Comment: for x86 yes this is true due to the amount of change per implementation.  x86 hand tuning in assembly is futile, hardly even educational.  But that is not true for assembly in general, x86 is barely a drop in the ocean to the number of processors made and sold.  Other architectures do not have this problem.

Comment: It would be much better if you can share some sample applications that beginners of assembly language can make.

Answer (score 4):

Steve Gibson writes almost all (if not all) of [his utilities](https://www.grc.com/freepopular.htm) in Assembler.

He even has a ["starter kit"](https://www.grc.com/smgassembly.htm) for writing Windows apps in Assembler.

Answer (score 3):

Since your computer always ends up running machine instructions in the end, you can write any application in any language.  "Any language" of course includes assembly language.

[WriteNow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WriteNow) is a good example of a relatively complicated application written in assembly language (68k in this case).

Comment: Depends on your definition of "can write". Humans most certainly can't write many applications in assembly with time and effort competitive with high-level languages.

Comment: Depends on your sanity/commitment.  The original [RollerCoaster Tycoon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RollerCoaster_Tycoon) was almost entirely written in assembly.

Comment: @delnan, agreed, but that doesn't make it impossible.

Comment: If you want to roll it old school, the first versions of [QEMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMM) were written in C and then all the rest were assembler written over (and extending) the original.

Comment: Again, depends on what you're talking about. Your argument only shows that it's theoretically feasible, and furthermore practical for automated translators (e.g. compilers). But as for humans writing arbitrarily complicated applications directly in assembly, well, its possibility is only slightly less theoretical and a red herring than the same thing with turing tarpits. To be clear: I'm not objecting to anything you're stating, I'm complaining that you're not specifying what each statement is referring to.